# Altium. Multichannel design. How to specify the repeat(port) connection order?

Tags: altium

I am doing a multichannel design with Altium. Each channel has an 2 input ports called ID0 and ID1 which are used to set the address (or ID) of each of the channels.

How do you specify the connection on the sheet entry?

[image]

For Example I would like to connect ID0 of Channel 1 to Vcc, ID0 of channel 2 to ground, ID0 of channel 3 to Vcc, etc...

I have tried as I show in the picture but it does not owrk (basically does not creat any connections at all.

Any ideas?

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's done with labels.

See [this](http://techdocs.altium.com/display/ADOH/Creating+a+Multi-channel+Design) example:

[image]

Comment: Ok, I was using a bus, but the issue was that all the net names and bus names need to be identical in order for it to work. Otherwise it doesn't understand the connectivity

Comment: The bus itself, unlike a wire, does not really affect connectivity- it's just a graphic object that is supposed to make things clearer to humans.